# How to nicely read "alternating" lines?

Tags: file, parsing, kotlin

I have a text file that contains lines that follow an alternate pattern, like:

```
name: SomeName 
counterA: 0, counterB: 0, counterC: 0
name: SomeNameB 
counterA: 1, counterB: 2, counterC: 3
...
```

I want to write a simple parser that pushes SameName, and the counters A to C into a new object.

So the task is basically to process always *two* lines together.

I started with this code:

```
fun readFileAsLinesUsingReadLines(fileName: String): List<String> = File(fileName).readLines()

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val lines = readFileAsLinesUsingReadLines("Whatever")
    for (i in (0 .. lines.size-1 step 2)) {
        println(lines[i]+lines[i+1])
    }
}
```

and yes, that prints

```
name: SomeName counterA: 0, counterB: 0, counterC: 0
```

which I can then further parse.

But I find that usage of `(0 .. lines-size-1 step)` to be not very elegant.

Are there more elegant, or "more kotlin" ways of pulling that information?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With [`useLines`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-reader/use-lines.html), you can read the lines as a (lazy) sequence, and then use [`chunked`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/chunked.html) with a transform lambda to parse and format as you see fit:

```
val result = File("file.txt").useLines { lines ->
    lines.chunked(2) { (l1, l2) -> l1 + l2 }.toList()
}

result.forEach { println(it) }
```

If, for some reason, you want to stream everything into memory first, you can also use [`readLines`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/read-lines.html) with the list-based version of [`chunked`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html):

```
val result = File("file.txt").readLines().chunked(2) { (l1, l2) -> l1 + l2 }

result.forEach { println(it) }
```

Comment: If you don't need the laziness, `chunked` also works on the `List<String>` that the `readLines` call returns.

Comment: Very nice, thanks. Especially the thing about `chunked` also working for lists.

Comment: In your `useLines` version shouldn't you add  `.toList()` after the closing bracket?

Comment: @mTak Depends on the further processing you want to do. There might be no need to stream things into memory at all.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen the stream is closed after useLines so the printing of the lines will not succeed afterwards. So either you print inside the lambda or you cast to list and print afterwards.

Comment: @mTak Documentation says stream is closed after processing finished. Not behind a PC anymore so will try later.

Comment: mTak is right... using the sequence it could throw an `IOException` "stream closed" on the `result.forEach`-line.

Comment: @Roland I tested this exact code and had no exceptions. Maybe buffering saved me because I only used a file with the 4 example lines from the question?

Comment: @Roland I'm on Linux. Will re-test once I'm behind a PC again. Will add the `toList()` for now.

Comment: @Roland I was wrong. Even for a small file size the `IOException` occurs for me as well. Either there's some non-deterministic behavior, or I royally messed up in my testing yesterday. Probably the latter :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
(0 until lines.size).filter { it % 2 == 0 }.forEach { println(lines[it] + lines[it+1]) }
```

or as Roland prefers:

```
lines.indices.filter { it % 2 == 0 }.forEach { println(lines[it] + lines[it+1]) }
```

Comment: Appreciated, but I find the other answer way more elegant ;-)

Comment: if you just want to use the `indices` you could also just call `lines.indices.filter ...`. An alternative to that: `lines.forEachIndexed { i, s-> if (i%2==0) print(s) else println(s) }`... but the `chunked()`-method is way more clear I think. Additionally with the destructured list it becomes also way more readable (depending which names you want to give ;-)).

Comment: @Roland of course there are many ways to treat and filter the indices and the chunked method is clear, it's just the simplicity of the thing that makes me prefer the indices way.

Comment: In the question *does it start at 0* is a fact.

Comment: So you think that it would be better for a person with a background of a 1 based index language saw `indices` instead of `0 until lines.size`?

Comment: Of course I use (occasionally) indices when needed and I could have used it here but it's not important (in fact it's exactly the same) and about newcomers to Kotlin I strongly disagree.