# How to build list from a "chunked" block?

Tags: collections, kotlin, collectors

I am processing input data that comes in "alternating" lines.

In order to handle that nicely, I (and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52035986/how-to-nicely-read-alternating-lines)) came up with this code:

```
val foobars = mutableListOf<FooBar>()

lines.chunked(2) { (l1, l2) ->
    foobars.add( FooBar( generateFoo(l1), generateBar(l2) )
}
```

The above works, but it seems a bit odd to first create that empty list, and to then append to it in order to "collect" the freshly created objects.

If this would be a Java stream, the "collecting" part would be straight forward, using a List collector.

Now I am wondering if there is more elegant/canonical way of collecting my list items in kotlin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually simpler then you think, e.g.

```
val foobars = lines.chunked(2) { (l1, l2) ->
  FooBar( generateFoo(l1), generateBar(l2) )
}.toMutableList()
```

The difference to a Java stream is, that you can actually operate on a list (/sequence/iterable) directly and you get a new one in return every time you call something like `chunked`, `filter`, `map`, `toList`, `toMutableList`, etc. So after calling `chunked` (+ transformation) you got a new list containing the transformations. You then can transform it to a (new) mutable list just by calling `toMutableList()`.

And if you do not need to alter the list later, you can just skip `toMutableList()` and you have your list already.

Comment: I used `toMutableList()` to allow adding entries. Your example works nicely with `toList()` in the end!

Comment: That's true... i just used `mutableList` because you did... I didn't think that you do not need to alter it later ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat if `lines` is an `Iterable` you even don't need to call `.toList()` because `chunked` already returns a `List`.

Comment: Thanks @Ilya for the comment. You are right, another `toList()` at the end is just redundant.